# Likelihood ratio test statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

It is claimed that LED light bulbs will last an average of 10000 hours. A box of 100 of these bulbs is purchased. Each bulb is then tested until it burns out, with its lifetime being recorded. The lifetimes of the bulbs, $y_i, i\in \{1,\dots, 100\}$, are given in hours and are modelered as i.i.d. Exponential($\theta$) random variables. The sample mean is $\overline{y}=9845$.

I would like to determine the value of the likelihood ratio test statistic $\lambda(\theta_0)$ to test $H_0:\theta =10000$ against $H_a: \theta\ne 10000$, but I'm quite confused in the concepts.

How exactly can I do this? Should I evaluate $\lambda(10000)$? Also, how is the p-value determined based on $\lambda(\theta_0)$?

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Using the exponential distribution seems like a strange choice to me. Is it true that the the frequency of burning times decreases monotonously with the burning times?

Comment: @citronrose Unfortunately, such information is not provided. I need to base my answer on what is given.